# Tensorflow scan multiple matrix rows with offset

Tags: python, tensorflow

#### Question

I want to scan a matrix analogous to Tensorflow's `tf.scan()`, but using multiple rows at a time. So given a `[n, m]` matrix, I want to be able to iterate the `m` rows (with `n` elements) from `i + j` to `m` giving `m - j` slices of shape `[i - j, n]`.

How can this be achieved?

I know how `tf.scan` does something like this, returning the accumulated value of each iteration. But I don't think shifting the matrix as multiple inputs solves this, since the values that have an offset cannot be precomputed.

#### Example

To give an example for `n = 3` and `m = 5`, let's say I have a matrix that looks like the following:

```
# [[1 0 0]
#  [1 1 0]
#  [0 0 0]   row 3
#  [0 0 0]   row 4
#  [0 0 0]]  row 5

matrix_shape = [5, 3]
matrix_idx = tf.constant([[0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1]])
matrix = tf.scatter_nd(matrix_idx,
                       tf.ones(tf.shape(matrix_idx)[0],
                               dtype=tf.int32),
                       matrix_shape)
```

I want to apply the following function from row 3 to row 5:

```
# [[ 1  0  0]    ┌ a
#  [ 1  1  0]    ├ b
#  [ 6  4  2]  <─┴ output / current line
#  [16 12  6]
#  [46 34 18]]

def compute(x):
    a = x[0]
    b = x[1]
    return (a + b + 1) * 2
```

Does Tensorflow have a function specific to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code I wrote does exactly what I wanted.

The important part here is the `return` of the function used by `tf.scan`, which not only gives back the current computation `c`, but also the row from the previous step `b`. It is therefore important to later cut off this excess from `computation` by only selecting the later tensor in this list with `[1]`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import tensorflow as tf

def compute(x, _):
    a = x[0]
    b = x[1]
    c = (a + b + 1) * 2
    return (b, c)

matrix_shape = tf.constant([3, 3])
init_data = [[1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0]]
initializer = (
    tf.constant(init_data[0]),
    tf.constant(init_data[1]),
)
matrix = tf.zeros(matrix_shape, dtype=tf.int32)
computation = tf.scan(compute, matrix, initializer)[1]
result = tf.concat((tf.constant(init_data), computation), axis=0)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(result)
    print(result.eval())
```

Since I'm yet lacking experience: May this solution be bad for performance, because the function is returning a tuple and therefore not using Tensorflow's speed optimizations?